# visualforce tab not showing in navigation tab in service cloud console

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, app, tab, servicecloud

i recently migrated an app from sandbox to prod. this is a service cloud console app. It has a visualforce tab which is working fine in sandbox. Tab got migrated in prod. I can see preview of visualforce page in prod.

When i edit the app from setup menu, tab is getting displayed in available tabs and selected tabs list. When i launch the application and choose customize my tabs from navigation menu, tab is not visible in available and selected tabs.

Comment: This looks something with your user record to me or profile. Do you have service cloud user check box checked for your user?

Comment: yes, i have checked service cloud user for the user. Does the profile need to have access to page / controller. Although i could not see even after giving user Sys Admin profile.

Comment: Profile > Custom Tab Settings. It was set as Hidden by default for custom Visualforce based tabs. Setting this to Default On solved the problem. Thanks. This was related to profile setting.