# Migrate Case Support Settings like Default Case Owner

Tags: case, ant, migration-tool, migration

Can Case Support Settings like Default Case Owner, automated case user be migrated from sandbox to production using ant migration tool by just including case object or they need to be migrated manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be migrated as metadata is available for case settings

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
    <members>Case</members>
     <name>Settings</name>
   </types>
  <version>35.0</version>
 </Package>
```

Anything that has metadata available will be migrated .More info refer metadata guide

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf

To overcome the difference in owner ,Manually find the XML file for case settings .It will be under settings folder and casesettings file and modify the User owner as relevant to PROD

Comment: Thanks, what should be done if the user who will be set as Default Case Owner is only available only in production and not in sandbox ? I found the user / email issue while migrating Email Alerts related to workflow as well.

Comment: Manually find the XML file for case settings .It will be under settings folder and casesettings file and modify the User owner as relevant to PROD

Comment: Everything you will see in XML metadata file and edit the emails and use your PROD environment emails as applicable .

Comment: can you please have a look at this question and suggest : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101318/visualforce-tab-not-showing-in-navigation-tab-in-service-cloud-console

Comment: <types>
    <members>Case</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
   </types>